# Reading attributes in an XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to read a file that looks like this:

```
<tasks>
  <task name="Project Management" mode="Automatic" start="07/01/2012 00:00" duration="21" id="954471332"></task>
  <task name="Conception/Approval" mode="Automatic" start="07/01/2012 00:00" duration="6" percentComplete="1" id="1905425539"></task>
  <task name="Define Initial Scope" start="07/04/2012 00:00" finish="07/18/2012 00:00" percentComplete="0.31" id="1154759651"></task>
</tasks>
```

I only want the values of `name`, `start`, and `finish` or `duration`, whichever exists.

This is what I have so far:

```
XElement allData = XElement.Load(dlg.FileName);
if (allData != null)
{
    IEnumerable<XElement> tasks = allData.Descendants("task");
    foreach (XElement task in tasks)
    {

    }
}
```

I'm sure I have to use the Attribute method but I'm not sure how to use it or the syntax.

Comment: <task name="Define Initial Scope" start="07/04/2012 00:00" finish="07/18/2012 00:00" percentComplete="0.31" id="1154759651">

<task name="Project Management" mode="Automatic" start="07/01/2012 00:00" duration="21" id="954471332">


These are a could of the tasks in my XML file

Comment: your sample XML did not show up in your question? can you try to put it in?

Comment: Its in now, wouldnt accept the main <tasks> tag

Comment: So it's rooted with a `tasks` element?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to get the attributes:

```
XElement allData = XElement.Load(dlg.FileName);
if (allData != null)
{
    IEnumerable<XElement> tasks = allData.Descendants("task");
    foreach (XElement task in tasks)
    {
        task.Attribute("name").Value;
        task.Attribute("start").Value;
        task.Attribute("finish").Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you want to use `allData.Elements("task")` to be more specific.

Comment: When i add these into my project i get the error

"Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Comment: This will crash, if one of the attributes does not exist, which can happen according to the question. Add a check for null to the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend getting only the elements and values you need before looping through them:

```
XElement allData = XElement.Load(dlg.FileName);
if (allData != null)
{
  var tasks = allData.Descendants("task")
                     .Where(e => e.Attribute("name") != null
                                 && (e.Attribute("start") != null
                                     || e.Attribute("finish") != null))
                     .Select(e => new 
                     {
                       Name = e.Attribute("name").Value,
                       Start = e.Attribute("start").Value,
                       Finish = e.Attribute("finish").Value,
                     });
  foreach(var task in tasks)
  {
    // task.Name will have a value
    // task.Start and/or task.Finish will have a value.
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you using as the scope for e in this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by scope.  the value `e` in my example could be anything, it's just a lambda parameter, and in this example represents the value of an `XElement`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a object Tasks, how about something like:

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(dlg.FileName);
  List<Task> infos = from c in doc.Descendants("task")
              select new Task (c.Element("name").Value, c.Element("start).Value, 
              c.Element("finish").Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(dlg.FileName);
var query = doc.Descendants("task")
    .Select(task => new
    {
        Name = (string)task.Attribute("name"),
        Start = (DateTime)task.Attribute("start"),
        Finish = (DateTime?)task.Attribute("finish"),
        Duration = (long?)task.Attribute("duration"),
    });
```

The `Finish` or `Duration` fields will be null if the corresponding attribute does not exist.

Then just loop through the items in the query to do as you wish.

```
foreach (var item in query)
{
    var app = c1Schedule1.DataStorage.AppointmentStorage.Appointments.Add();
    app.Subject = item.Name;
    app.Start = item.Start;
    if (item.Finish != null)
    {
        app.Finish = item.Finish.Value;
    }
    if (item.Duration != null)
    {
        app.Duration = item.Duration.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: If i wanted to use the query var what would the syntax look like in it, say im making a new appointment for C1Schedule:
`code`
Appointment app;
app = c1Schedule1.DataStorage.AppointmentStorage.Appointments.Add();
app.Subject = query.Select<Name>;
`code`


I tried the query.select<Name> but apparently thats not it.

Comment: Well it's a query so you'd have to loop through it and grab the values from the items in the query.  I've shown an example of how you might do so.

Comment: Another quick question hopefully you can answer. I did my input this way you showed me and everything worked fine. Say that i want to have a button to update my Schedule with the Gantt chart im using. When i hit the button im trying to save the XML file and then reload it using this method, only thing is that when i go to load it i get an ArgumentNullException starting with the "new" after the .Select

Comment: My best guess is that you have a `task` that does not have a `start` attribute that is a valid date.  The code assumes that it exists.  The other fields doesn't necessarily have to exist (since `string`, `DateTime?` and `long?` are nullable values indicating they don't exist).